# Нужен алгоритм для поиска всех возможных комбинаций длины k, из массива длины n

Tags: java, алгоритм

Нужен алгоритм для поиска всех возможных комбинаций длины k, из массива длины n (n > k), порядок элементов не имеет значения. Лучшее что я смог придумать это k-раз вложенные циклы, но этот вариант ужасный, т.к будет огромное кол-во повторений

Comment: Это называется генерация сочетаний, и рассматривается в томе 4А "*Искусства программирования*" Кнута, раздел 7.2.1.3.

Comment: Например: целое длины n-бит. Одним циклом выбираем все числа, где k-бит равны 1.